# Flutter: Added an additional TextFormField to Column but no change in display

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am making a Form which takes a table as its child.
There is a button to add additional Column and another button to add additional TextFormField. The buttons are implemented the _MyHomePageState.

So, the setup is like the one in the link below.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#the-parent-widget-manages-the-widgets-state

When the addTextFormField method is invoked, a new TextFormField is added to List _textFormFields. The List _columns takes _textFormFields as children. Therefore, _columns is also changed. _columns is then passed to FormA constructor through build.

At this moment, there is 1 Column Widget in _columns and 2 TextFormFields in the Column Widget. However, it only displays 1 TextFormField.

Then when I press addColumn button, an additional Column with two TextFormFields will appear.

Why there are not 2 TextFormFields when I press addTextFormField?

main.dart

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

      List<Widget> _columns;
      List<Widget> _textFormFields;

      @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
          _columns = List<Widget>();
          _textFormFields = List<Widget>();

          _addTextFormField();
          _addColumn();
      }

      void _addTextFormField() async {
          _textFormFields.add(TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: _textFormFields.length.toString()),
                        ),
                      );

          for(Column column in _columns){
            print('from _addTextFormField ' + column.children.length.toString()); 
           // press addTextFormField button once, it prints  2

            print('from _addTextFormField ' + column.children.toString()); 
           //press addTextFormField button once, it prints [TextFormField, TextFormField]
          }

          setState((){

          });
      }

      void _addColumn() async {

          print('from addColumn   no. of textFormFields ' + _textFormFields.length.toString());
          _columns.add(Column(
                      children: _textFormFields,),
                      );

          for(Column column in _columns){
            print('from addColumn   no. of widget in a column ' + column.children.length.toString());
          }

          setState((){
          });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        print('rebuild');
        // press addTextFormField button once, it prints rebuild
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FormA (columns : _columns),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          floatingActionButton: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _addColumn,
                  tooltip: '+C',
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _addTextFormField,
                  tooltip: '+R',
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
            ],
          ),


        );
      }
    }
```

formA.dart

```
class FormA extends StatelessWidget{

  FormA({Key key, this.columns})
      : super(key: key);

  List<Widget> columns;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      for(Column column in columns){
        print('from FormA   no. of widget in a column ' + column.children.length.toString());
       // press addTextFormField button once, it prints 2
        print('from FormA ' + column.children.toString());
       // press addTextFormField button once, it prints [TextFormField, TextFormField]
      }

    return Form(
      child: Table(
        children: [TableRow(
          children: columns,
        ),],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code in its current form will not work as you expect because the `_columns` list even though has the reference to `_textFormFields`, the `Column` widget you initially built has its `children` already built and will not change if you change it `MyhomePage` widget because it will not have its reference.

In its current form you code works like this.
[image]

All you need to do is reassign the `_columns` field in the `setState` of `_addTextFormField` method which will rebuild the whole list of columns like this.

```dart
void _addTextFormField() {
    _textFormFields.add(
      TextFormField(
        decoration:
            InputDecoration(hintText: _textFormFields.length.toString()),
      ),
    );

    for (Column column in _columns) {
      print('from _addTextFormField ' + column.children.length.toString());
      // press addTextFormField button once, it prints  2

      print('from _addTextFormField ' + column.children.toString());
      //press addTextFormField button once, it prints [TextFormField, TextFormField]

    }

    setState(() {
      _columns = List<Column>.generate(
          _columns.length, (index) => Column(children: _textFormFields));
    });
  }
```

After this change it will look like this.

[image]

Here is a live code pen with the solution.

https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/dyYRVrL

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain more why the Column widget does not have a reference to _textFormFields? I assign _textFormFields as the children widget of Column widget when _addColumn is initially invoked. When _addTextFormField is invoked again, it prints [TextFormField, TextFormField] in FormA's "built" method. Doesn't it mean the Column widget inside _columns still has the reference?

Comment: Becuase in flutter widgets are immutable. Check this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L1832-L1889) for the documentation of the `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget` which is what the `Column` class implements. In the comments its clearly mentioned why this is not possible.

Comment: One of the reasons I think this is necessary is that, the Column widget has to rebuild in order to effectively calculate how to layout its children.

Answer (score 0):

> Then when I press addColumn button, an additional Column with two
>   TextFormFields will appear.
>
> Why there are not 2 TextFormFields when I press addTextFormField?

Not really! When the widget initializes, you have exactly one `Column` and exactly one `TextFormField` in each List. Now you press `addColumn` so one more `Column` is added. So you have two `Column`s but still one `TextFormField`.

I hope that helps.